# UIImage animation in collection view cell deletes as soon as its selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a view controller that contains a TableView and a CollectionView simultaneously. I basically want to use the tableview to select specific exercises, and the collectionview will show animations of the exercises being performed. The thing is when the animations are loaded in the cell, if i select a cell the animation disappears. Here are some pics below:[image: before selection] [image: after cell of containing animation is selected]

Is there a proper or better way to do this? Basically I want the user to be able to select "Leg Day Routine" and on the right I want the animations of the exercises to show so the user can see the exercises. Right now the animations disappear as soon as I press a collectionview cell.

Comment: The information that you have given here is limited. But may be it is happening because white is the selection color of the collectionViewCell.

Comment: That makes alot of sense... it removes the animation aswell. Any idea on how I could go about and fix it? @dRAGONAIR

Comment: can you try to remove the selection color and see if it works. else you might need to put breakpoint in didSelectCell and check out what is happening to the cell's subviews.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help. Is there a better way to do what i'm trying to do? I basically just want exercises to be shown in a scroll view on the side of my tableview. @dRAGONAIR

Comment: The way you are doing is ok. But its again subjected to the UI spec. from the screenshot, it looks like its designed for iPhone.

In my opinion, this design, of showing both the tables side by side, whould be awesome in iPad(in iPad you can directly use splitViewController). 

For iphone, due to less display space, it would be better if u show the exercise in a popup tableView controller. doing so, u will be able to use more space and the UI will look neat. Just a suggestion :)